# Updating a foreign key only when primary key exists

Tags: database, postgresql, join, updates

I have the following piece of code. I want to update a foreign key
if the corresponding primary key exists.

Please look at Query No : 2 and Query No : 3.

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS s CASCADE;  
CREATE SCHEMA s;

CREATE TABLE s.t1 (
    "id1" BigSerial,
    "id2" BigInt,
    CONSTRAINT "pk1" PRIMARY KEY (id1)
)
WITH(OIDS=FALSE);    

CREATE TABLE s.t2 (
    "id3" BigSerial,
    "id4" Varchar UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "pk2" PRIMARY KEY (id3)
)
WITH(OIDS=FALSE);

ALTER TABLE s.t1 ADD CONSTRAINT "fk" FOREIGN KEY (id2) REFERENCES s.t2 (id3) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;       

INSERT INTO s.t2 (id3, id4) VALUES (1, 'hello');
INSERT INTO s.t2 (id3, id4) VALUES (21, 'hello2');
INSERT INTO s.t2 (id3, id4) VALUES (31, 'hello3');
INSERT INTO s.t1 (id1, id2) VALUES (2, 21);
INSERT INTO s.t1 (id1) VALUES (3);

SELECT id1, id2 FROM s.t1;

UPDATE s.t1
SET id2 = (SELECT id3 FROM s.t2 WHERE s.t2.id4 = 'hello') WHERE s.t1.id1 = 2; 

SELECT id1, id2 FROM s.t1;
```

QUERY 2

```
UPDATE s.t1
SET id2 = (SELECT id3 FROM s.t2 WHERE s.t2.id4 = 'xyz') WHERE s.t1.id1 = 2
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM s.t2 WHERE s.t2.id4 = 'xyz');

SELECT id1, id2 FROM s.t1;
```

QUERY 3

```
UPDATE s.t1
SET id2 = (SELECT id3 FROM s.t2 WHERE s.t2.id4 = 'hello3') WHERE s.t1.id1 = 2
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM s.t2 WHERE s.t2.id4 = 'hello3');

SELECT id1, id2 FROM s.t1;

DROP SCHEMA s CASCADE;
```

Is it possible to do the above queries in a efficient way through join perhaps. I do not wish to call essentially the same sub query twice. I am currently doing so. Once for the EXISTS statement and one for the main query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) to evaluate the sub-query just once and then use it multiple times:

```
WITH find_rec AS
  (SELECT id3 FROM s.t2 WHERE id4 = 'hello3')
UPDATE s.t1
SET id2 = find_rec.id3
WHERE id1 = 2
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM find_rec);
```

More in general, you should **never manually assign a value to a `bigserial` column**. The next time you create a record from the sequence behind the `id1` or `id3` columns you will get a primary key violation. The whole purpose of the `bigserial` type is to let PostgreSQL manage the primary key values.

Comment: A followup question. Does it help the database to analyze the query if the full query is listed as it is. I mean if there are some fields in the main query which depend on the find_rec. 

I understand there may not be a straight forward answer and it may depend.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the answer would be no. The query planner evaluates every new query it encounters and it will choose the fastest plan it can piece together. Dependencies between sub-queries are usually solved efficiently, the query planner usually knows best. What would help the query planner is to regularly do a `VACUUM ANALYZE` on your database because that generates the statistics that the query planner uses.